# Can i collect everything in a level in the first run?

Tags: deadcore

I completed the first story level *The Fall* and looking at the starts I only got 1 Spark, 1 Log and 1 Track.

After proceeding into the next level and then quitting out to redo the first level I see that the Switch Gun I get later on is with me from the very start, and when I go into Story Mode i see there are 3 more things to unlock, Dash, G-Mod and Blast.

Before completing the first level i was given the choice to continue or restart. i am wondering if i am able to collect everything in a level the first time through it? or will i need to come back to them with the other unlocks